# Concatenate all files from directory and subdirectories in CMD

Tags: cmd

How should I concatenate all files from directory and subdirectories in CMD?

I've tried `copy /b *.txt output.txt` but its not working.

I have these folders:

```
test
 - a1
 - a2 - a3 
      - a4 - a5 
 - a3
```

And in each folder i have some txt files.

Comment: What exact command are you executing, and what are the results i.e. how is it not working?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could simply iterate over all text files in all folders and append them all to the same output file. Something like the following:

```
del output.txt
for /R %F in (*.txt) do type "%F" >> output.txt
```

You may need to exclude `output.txt` from being added as well (or put it in a different location):

```
for /R %F in (*.txt) do if not "%~nxF"=="output.txt" type "%F" >> output.txt
```

Comment: I need without iteration.

Comment: Honestly: Why? *Something* has to iterate over all files anyway.

Comment: `for /r` returns a path, to exclude you should either use `if "%~nxF" neq "output.txt"` or `if "%F" neq "%cd%\output.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

If you could consider using PowerShell, this would gather the file contents into one file.

```
DEL "%TEMP%\output.txt" 2>NUL
powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Get-Content | Add-Content $Env:TEMP/output.txt }"
```

If you would like something more cryptic and cmd shell-like, the aliases could be used.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "gci -file -rec | gc | ac %TEMP%/out.txt }"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just iterate the folders which would probably be quicker than iterating the files!

Run this from `\test` at the prompt:

```dos
(For /D /R %A In (*) Do @Type "%A\*.txt" 2>Nul)>output.txt
```

Or from anywhere, *(other than within the sources' directories)*, replacing `FullorRelativePath\` as necessary:

```dos
(For /D /R "FullorRelativePath\test" %A In (*) Do @Type "%A\*.txt" 2>Nul)>output.txt
```

Another method would be to use `FindStr` but because it prepends each line with the name of the file, you'd need to run it through a `For /F` to output just the required token(s).

Run this from anywhere, *(other than within the sources' directories)*, replacing `FullorRelativePath\` as necessary:

```dos
(For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %A In ('FindStr /S "^" "FullorRelativePath\test\*.txt" 2^>Nul') Do @Echo(%B)>output.txt
```